# Coppie di pronomi atoni "Ce ne"

Tags: word-meaning, grammar, sentences

Are the transformations below using pronouns correct :

> Hanno imposto a noi delle regole ferree.

I am quite confident about this ->

> Ci hanno imposto delle regole ferree.

Is this correct? ->

> Ce n'hanno imposto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation "Ci hanno imposto delle regole ferree." is correct, the second should be:

> Ce le hanno imposte.

Comment: delle is for di + le then it should be ne and not le ?

Comment: @kiriloff You are referring to the "regole ferree" mentioned above (a specific reference), so I would use "the". I would use "ne" only to indicate a quantity, for example, "Ce ne hanno imposte quattro/alcune."

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow Actually, it's not about a quantity, but their existence. "Non dovreste rispettare regole" -> "Ce ne hanno imposte" or "Forse dovreste seguire delle regole" -> "Non ce ne hanno imposte".

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow so arguably Ce ne hanno imposte is also correct, it just means we don't focus on which regole, just some ?

Comment: @kiriloff Yes if you don' t focus, but if you already mentioned the rules is better to use "le"